# how to convert Convert AM/PM time to 24 hours format at the computed field of DataTable in LotusApplications/Xpage?

Tags: time, date-formatting, xpages-ssjs

Can any one help me out . I want to display a time field as 24 Hour format inside the dataTable while designing an XPage lotus application.
e.g.  11:00PM  should be displayed/converted to 2300 Hour

Answer (score 0):

Use a computed text value and attach a converter. The converter follows the pattern as laid out in the Java API documentation for the [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) class. To display the current time in 24 hour format showing hours and minutes only, without a separater :

```
<xp:text value="#{javascript:@Now();}">
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertDateTime pattern="HHmm"></xp:convertDateTime>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

Comment: Thanks Simon Delicata , it works when I use @Now() in computed field . But When I compute the value of time input field into data table computed field it does not show in 24 hour format. Actually , I am having an time input field , the user enters the time and then after document creation , datatable print the time value . the following code is using for computed field to show time (24 hour format) :                                     var dt:NotesDateTime = datatable1.getItemValue("inputTimevalue").toString();
dt= @Replace(@Text((@Middle(dt,12,11))),"ZE","");
return dt;

Comment: Could you include an example of what you are doing?

Comment: I have a time input field .when user enters the time and save the record , the datatable populate the values . in datatable I have used computed text value to display time. I want to display this time in 2400 hour format.